# Pass stateparam to controller set in stateprovider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
    $stateProvider.state('page2', {
      url: '/page2/:topicId',
      templateUrl: 'page2.html',
      controller : 'page2Ctrl'

});

app.controller('page2Ctrl', ['$scope', 'getContentService', function($scope,getContentService){
    getContentService.request().success(function(data){
        $scope.content = data;
    });
}]);
```

I want to pass topicId to page2Ctrl. I know there's a way passing it using resolve in the stateprovider but for me that's not so modular. How can I pass topicId to page2Ctrl without using resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add $stateParams as an injection

```
app.controller('page2Ctrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'getContentService',
                     function($scope,   $stateParams,   getContentService){
    // you can now use $stateParams.topicID
    getContentService.request().success(function(data){
        $scope.content = data;
    });
}]);
```

Comment: what is the different btw $stateParams vs $stateParam?

Comment: I can't readily find code examples with `$stateParam` and am not sure it exists